# XMLHttpRequest not working with FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a form in which the user can upload images and pdf-files. Right now I'm trying to convert the pdf-files into jpg-files, in order to be able to preview them BEFORE the form gets submitted.

Here is the form:

```
<form>
    <div class="fileUpload">
        <p class="fileformats">Valid formats: jpg/png/gif/jpeg/pdf</p><br>
        <input type="file" name="overlayfile[]" class="src" onchange="preview(this)">
        <img src="img/someimage.jpg" class="target"/>
    </div>
</form>
<p id="item"></p>
```

The JavaScript Code which I use to preview the files and to send the XMLHttpRequest:

```
function preview(input) {

    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        if(input.files[0].type == "image/jpeg" || input.files[0].type == "image/gif") {
            reader.onload = function(e) {

                input.nextElementSibling.src = e.target.result;

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        } else if (input.files[0].type == "application/pdf") {

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var targeturl = e.target.result;
                getURL(targeturl);
            }
        }
    }
}

function getURL (item) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", "preview.php?url="+item, true);
    request.send();
}
```

(I did not write the function to convert the pdf-file into an image yet, currently I'm simply trying to pass the value of `target` as the content of my paragraph. I'm doing this because I would like to do it step by step so I do not miss any mistakes that would be very annoying later).

When I declare a variable in my `getURL()` function, it works just fine and the paragraph displays the value of the variable, however, when I call the function from  within `reader.onload` nothing happens.
Does anyone know why that is and how I can fix that?

If you need anymore code/ further explanations please let me know and thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need to upload them to the server. You could just create a iframe and show it.

Also, you don't need the filereader, creating a objectURL instead. It is faster and better. base64 is ~3 times larger and takes time to (de)compile.

```
function preview(input) {
  const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

  Array.from(input.files).forEach(file => {
    if (file.type.startsWith('image')) {
      input.nextElementSibling.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    } else if (file.type == 'application/pdf') {
      let iframe = document.createElement('iframe')

      iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      iframe.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("item").appendChild(iframe)
      }
      iframe.onerror = function(){
        // failed to load pdf
      }
    }
  })
}
```

if the iframe don't work for you due to something... POST the file to preview.php instead of sending it as base64 using `xhr.send(file)`

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! 
I will implement what you suggested, since it seems to be a better solution, however, unfortunately I have to convert the pdf-files to images, as they're supposed to be displayed just like images.